# iphone textview showing data coming from coredata

Tags: iphone, core-data, formatting, textview

I need to show some data in a textview coming from coredata (like this for example),
[image: what I need to show in textView]

I imagine a possible solution (dont know if is the right one or how to do it, please advice),
so bring the data from coredata to a string, appending all the data neeeded in the string with the equivalent of "\n" for new line where needed; then show the data in the text view,
(please refer to example image to know what is needed)

- so how to bring the data from coredata to this textView with this formatting?
- please note I only want to know if this is a proper way to do it (imagined solution? or if there is a more proper way?)

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: This isn't a site for getting code written to spec. Have you made an attempt at your app? What happened? Were there problems? If you haven't even attempted it yet -- break the problem down into various parts: accessing data in core data, displaying text in a text view. Make a start. Ask questions if you have more specific problems.

Comment: Im not asking to have my code written, just asking if the idea of using an string with appended data from coredata is plausible, as I have asked, for advice to know if the idea is right!, or there is another more elegant way!

Comment: Your question is confusing, then. You asked "so how to bring the data from coredata to this textView with this formatting?". It's certainly possible to do what you describe, yes! But the bit I just quoted sounds a bit like you're expecting the code to be dropped into your lap.

Comment: Well, ok, I'll answer the question you seem to want answering! See my answer.

Comment: in case the solution works?, I don't know if I can show an appended string with new line "\n" in a text view?? that's what I meant tnx

Comment: We're not telepathic, you have to actually ask the questions you want answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tackled an identical issue in one of my apps.

The approach I took was to first structure my core data model so that the pieces of data had enough granularity so that I could construct different views as required.  In other words, instead of one property for "name", I have three properties.  One for "first name", one for "middle name", and a third for "last name".  I also created a separate "data layer" object so that I could easily get to pieces of my data from anywhere in the app.

Next, to construct my view that shows data in a sort of form view.  Using Interface Builder, I simply laid out a view using primarily UILabel view objects as placeholders.  Then, as the user switches between person views, I call on the data layer object for pieces of data and just "fill in" in the UILabel placeholders.

I also render a PDF file in paragraph form.  Similar to what you are doing.  For that, I use an NSMutableString along with the NSString stringWithFormat convenience method.  Using NSMutableString, you can concatenate strings with newline characters embedded as needed.  For this, I also call on my data layer object for the pieces of data.

```
[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Date of Visit: %@", dateOfVisitString]   drawInRect:stringRect withFont:theFont];
```

Hope this helps.  Good Luck.

Comment: Edit: plug removed. Please don't advertise your company/app on Stackoverflow. Your answer is appreciated though! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your strategy of

> 'bring the data from coredata to a
>   string, appending all the data neeeded
>   in the string with the equivalent of
>   "\n" for new line where needed; then
>   show the data in the text view'

will work fine.

(Bit of an odd answer, but it seems to be what you're asking, from your comment clarification.)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is fine. If you're targeting a textview for display, then constructing a formatted string from a managed object's properties is reasonable. Use NSMutableString and its -appendFormat: method.

You may also want to explore creating a report form out of UILabels laid out inside a UIView. Interface Builder would be the tool to use for this, but you could also create this in code.